# Custom feature ids from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles

i've come across an issue with the generated feature ID from GeoServer. The generated ID is a concatenation of the layer id and the feature primary key, rendering something like 'assets-1234566' say.

Is there a way to control this format of the ID?

I'm using vector tiles rendered with the Mapbox js SDK and some of the SDK functionality requires the feature ID, but it can only be an integer. The string returned from GeoServer is not accepted by Mapbox so certain functions do not work as a result.

Anyone struck this before? Any ideas on a work around?

Comment: I don't think you can change it and certainly not to an integer, OGC fids are supposed to be globally unique and the best way for GeoServer to get close to that is to use the layerid and primary key

Comment: thanks @IanTurton, that was my expectation, but it can't hurt to ask!

Comment: See also this MVT feature request https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec/issues/94

Comment: For Googleability: I assume this is what GeoServer errors like "06 Nov 13:50:55 WARN [wms.mapbox] - Cannot obtain numeric id from featureId: layer.fid--4112316d_16e40f211ca_7321" hint at. They render fine with OpenLayers though.